# Can I change the Window Option and Resolution?

Tags: theme-hospital

So Origin are giving away Theme Hospital for free. I managed to pick up a copy and I'm having some optimization issues I was hoping you guys could help me with.

Can I change the game in the files from Full Screen to Windowed? Also Can I change the resolution of the game in the files? As I can't find options for the game at all in the ingame-menu.

Answer (score 2):

If you alt-tab it should now be in a window instead of full screen. However its a pretty small window unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be resizable.

Not sure about the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out CrosixTH which is the open source implementation of Theme Hospital. It does have resolution  settings and provides support for modern systems.